# facebook api version used in facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm getting the following alerts on Facebook Developers:

'MyApp currently has access to Graph API v2.2 which will reach the end of its 2-year lifetime on 27 March, 2017. To ensure a smooth transition, please migrate all calls to Graph API v2.3 or higher.'

and I'm using Facebook Android SDK 3.23.0.

How can I know the version of Graph API used in such Facebook Android SDK?

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem, and annoyingly, I couldn't find anything about this in documentation. You can, however, refer to these two links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-3.x
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4x

And induce that your version (3.23.0) is on either Graph API version 2.2 or 2.3 - couldn't quite figure out which one of the two it is. Alternatively it seems that you can call this function from your code:

```
com.facebook.internal.ServerProtocol.getAPIVersion();
```

This should return a String of the current Graph API version that you can log. In my case, for SDK version 4.0.1, it was Graph API "v2.3"

Update: It seems that in newer versions of the FB SDK (just tried it in v4.23.0), `getApiVersion()` has been changed into `getDefaultAPIVersion()`. Seems to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! This help me a lot

Comment: How to get the same in iOS (Objective C) ? If you have any idea would be a great help! Thanks

Comment: It works for me to use `com.facebook.internal.ServerProtocol.getDefaultAPIVersion()` with FB SDK v4.28.0, the Graph API version is `2.11`

Comment: Your answer is what helped me mostly , but check the below thread which contains all the version supportinng of APis depending on SDK Version , but does require quite the scrolling . Anyone wondering which api version is supported by SDK version 5.9.0 upwards its API Version 5.0    https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 3):

[See this image for answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovadx.png)

you can change version in fb application dashboard under settings -> advanced for both testing and production version

Comment: @VadimTofan the option is still available in facebook developer portal.
 If you meant anything else, then please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

The current, latest version of the Graph API is **v2.8** and SDK version is **4.19.0**. you should have upgrade it.

Add the compile dependency with the latest version of the Facebook SDK in the build.gradle file

```
dependencies { 
     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

Can see reference link-

- [developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)
- [developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api).

Comment: I know which ones are the latest versions. However my question aims to ask about which Graph API version is using each android SDK version

Answer (score -1):

I think we can determine which Graph API version is using each android SDK version by updating the timeline.

Can see reference link

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refrain from posting such dumps of text in an answer. A link to your source is ok.