# Upgrade version of Graph API Facebook in Mobile Apps

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Recently I got reminder from Facebook regarding updating my Graph API version to latest one as the one which my app is pointing to will deprecate soon.

After this I have gone through all the documents provided by Facebook developers and also to other StackOverFlow question.

But still I have some queries and doubts if someone can clarify for me.

> 1) How to find to which API my apps (In Android as well as iOS) are
>   pointing too ?

-- I have seen on my Dashboard and it is showing 2.5, but i have not specified this in my code anywhere, which means it will point to the minimum available version which is 2.5 for now. Which leads to my second question.

> 2) If I have not specified the version and it is automatically taking
>   the minimum supported version, then once it is deprecated it will not
>   automatically take the 2.6 version as least minimum version ?

-- In my API Upgrade Tool it is showing affected methods, and in **Android** platform I have used only Facebook Login, with Maven library and the code is already same as Facebook Developer Document for Login.

-- While my **iOS** Platform have written Methods for getting userfriend list and interest etc. But we are not using it anymore.

> 3) Do I need to change anything in my Android version to get it point
>   to the latest one ?

-- I don't have to handle if user does not allow to access to certain things i have already got it under control.

> 4) Do I need to remove unused code of Facebook APIs?

-- If i am not using it anymore then it should not have any problem with Facebook API Version thing right?

> 5) If I change version directly from DashBoard, What will be its
>   impact or do I need to change the code itself.

I am able to understand everything that I am reading for the Graph API, But still I am not able to figure it out or it is not getting fit in mind that why i need to do migrate API version just to let my user login using facebook for my app.

Comment: Unversioned API calls will always automatically use the lowest currently available version. You should probably use the override switch for App Roles first, that allows you to test your app against the specified API version using any admin/developer/tester account.

Comment: @CBroe So I have changed that to my latest version, so only the team of the app can test this ? and Will it take selected version at the time of login to my app ?

Comment: If you use “Upgrade Calls for App Roles”, then only those can test it. You could of course set “Upgrade All Calls” instead, but that would affect all app users immediately ... and that’s probably not what one’d call _testing_.

Comment: I've changed it, and tried login through both platform and it worked perfectly. So does that mean it is upgraded without any code changes for App Roles? How can i get the info that it is pointing to which API ?

Comment: If your app makes any additional API calls after the user logged in, then you should test those, too. _“How can i get the info that it is pointing to which API ?”_ - what do you mean, you just _specified_ which version to use by overwriting it using this setting?

Comment: Yes, I know but is there a way to get that info by debugging or something ? I want to be sure that this setting changes worked.!

Comment: Well if your app does anything (requesting permissions, making API calls) that doesn’t exist any more, you could perhaps test it that way - by provoking it to fail at such an expected point. Other than that, I guess you’ll ave to trust Facebook that they’ve implemented this correctly.

Comment: Hey check this answer, it returns current pointing API Version. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42511019/7316675 Facebook have given all the way to get the correct info so that we can trust it blindly. :)